# Is there an Excel function that sums multiple values each multiplied by a different lookup value?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, lookup

I am setting up an Excel workbook that will take material usages as inputs. I want to be able to multiply these inputs against known material compositions that I have entered in a table.

Currently I have been doing =usage material1*vlookup(material1,material table,index,false)+usage material2*vlookup(material2,material table,index,false).....

[image]

Is there an easier way to do this considering I have large sets of material usages? I really want to avoid having the same formula repeated up to 30 times in the same cell just to sum it all up.

I would like a formula that will automatically multiply material usage * looked up composition and sum this formula for all materials input.

Comment: Please create some mock data and expected Input/output.  it will help us understand.

Comment: Sure, say I have materials X, Y, and Z. Each material contains a certain amount of chemical A. So for example, X contains 10% A, Y contains 15% A, and Z contains 20% A. If I know I used 20 gallons of each X, Y, and Z, I would like the formula to lookup the amount of chemical A in each material which is known in a table. Then, I want the formula to sum X*A+Y*A+Z*A. 20 gal * 10% + 20 gal * 15% + 20 gal * 20%.

Comment: Additional information should be added to the question itself using [edit].  Also create a tabular layout of the data and expected output.  Words are harder to visualize than a table.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot with a quick example of what I have been doing so far. It accomplishes the goal, I just am curious as to whether or not there is any easier way to do this considering I have a lot more than 3 materials I need to calculate for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's another way...

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(F6:F8,A6:C6,G6:G8),A7:C7)
```

...which needs to be confirmed with just ENTER.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I over thought it.  the only caveat to this method is the table lookup must be unique, But in this instance it probably will be.

Comment: @ScottCraner Yes, I should have made it clear.  Thanks Scott.

Comment: @learnAsWeGo no it was overly complicated and an array formula too.  It was not worth keeping as it was not a method I would suggest.

Answer (score 2):

Fast but a bit complicated solution:

```
{=SUM(INDEX(G1:G4,N(IF(1,MATCH(A1:A5000,F1:F4,0))))*B1:B5000)}
```

Another solution:

```
{=SUM(LOOKUP(A1:A5000,F1:F4,G1:G4)*B1:B5000)}
```

As noted in comments: lookup table must be sorted in ascending order. Also, if a match does not exist for a lookup value, it finds an approximate match, which likely is not the desired result.

[image]

**SPEED TEST WITH 5000 EXECUTIONS OF FORMULA:**

```
{=SUM(LOOKUP(A1:A5000,F1:F4,G1:G4)*B1:B5000)}
```

**5.237412 Seconds Elapsed | 16,325,977 Ticks Elapsed**

```
{=SUM(INDEX(G1:G4,N(IF(1,MATCH(A1:A5000,F1:F4,0))))*B1:B5000)}
```

**7.941025 Seconds Elapsed | 24,753,637 Ticks Elapsed**

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(F1:F4,A1:A5000,G1:G4),B1:B5000)
```

**12.338439 Seconds Elapsed | 38,461,185 Ticks Elapsed**

Comment: It should also be mentioned, though, that the lookup table must be sorted in ascending order.  Also, if a match does not exist for a lookup value, it finds an approximate match, which likely is not the desired result.

Comment: @Domenic you are absolutely right. I enjoy testing these and looking for the fastest solution. For the life of me I cannot come up with something better than yours! I gave you a +1 :-)

Comment: @Domenic found one more. complicated but works. learned how to return an array from index in process. this problem was fun. still like your answer best.

Comment: It was not surprising that the `LOOKUP` version was faster, since it uses binary search.  But it's surprising that `INDEX` is faster than `SUMIF`.  Very interesting, thanks for sharing the results.